# How to give elevation to an image in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, elevation

I have to implement elevation (like a shadow) on an image widget, but I couldn't find a solution to this. Is there a way to implement elevation to an image?

An image example of what I want to remove:
[image: what I want to remove]

I used the `Material` widget, but it renders empty space!! The original image has no spaces, how can I remove them?

Comment: Wrap it with https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html

Comment: I tried but what it makes square elevation, my image is circle

Answer (score 39):

You can simply use the `Material` or the `Card` widget:

```dart
Center(
  child: Material( // with Material
    child: Image.network('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
    elevation: 18.0,
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  ),
),
Center(
  child: Card( // with Card
    child: Image.network('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
    elevation: 18.0,
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  ),
),
```

If you want more control on the `Radius` of the Image. Then you can use `CircleAvatar`:

```dart
Center(
  child: Card(
    child: CircleAvatar(
      maxRadius: 54.0,
      backgroundImage:
          NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
    ),
    elevation: 18.0,
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  ),
),
```

Comment: @PrivacyofAnimal looks like you are using `padding` widget in between. My solutions works as standalone you can run them. - with-out seeing your code its hard to debug.